# Buck converter ouptut zero voltage

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, switching-regulator

I've designed PCB which uses [TPS54531](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps54531.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1611547885120) to generate 5v from 12v input. The circuit as below is similar to the reference circuit from TI.

[image]

After powered on, the VCC5_TMP read abnormal value 0 instead of expected 5v. Then I measured PH(pin8) as below which is also incorrect.
[image]

After that, I measured the VIN(=12v) and EN(>1.25v) which are all good.
[image]
[image]

After these measurements, I still can't get the reason why 5v can't be generated correctly. The power supply and the EN control are all correct and all the other components are selected as reference circuit suggested. Can someone help me to find the error in this circuit? Thanks.

[Update]
The problem is diode D2 is welded in the wrong direction. After I fixed it, everything is ok now.

Comment: Hit the edit button at the bottom of your question and use the build in schematic editor to add a schematic of the circuit you actually built, including actual component values to the question.

Comment: Check if the grounds are connected, components are correct, and soldered properly. If still the problem persists then post your PCB and placement here. Remember that any short circuit across the load causes the SMPS switcher to stop.

Comment: Is the diode the right way around?

Comment: @Justme Thank you for reminding. Yes, the diode is placed in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the symptoms, it is likely that diode is incorrectly mounted.